Почему бот не видит отмеченных в сообщении пользователей?
Разрабатывая бота для телеграмма, я столкнулся с проблемой получения пользователя из сообщений.
Сообразил что-то такое:
List<MessageEntity> entities = update.getMessage().getEntities();
for (MessageEntity entity : entities)
    if (entity.getUser() != null) {
        return entity.getUser();
    }
return null;

Но бот не видит отмеченных в сообщении пользователей.

То есть список entities получается пустой?

Список не пустой, но getUser всегда выдаёт null

Вы не сможете получить пользователя через getUser, если тип entity - mention.
Пример entity с типом mention и text_mention:
"message": {
    ...
    "text": "@Username",
    "entities": [
        {
            "offset": 0,
            "length": 9,
            "type": "mention"
        }
    ]
}

"message": {
    ...
    "text": "Username",
    "entities": [
        {
            "offset": 0,
            "length": 8,
            "type": "text_mention",
            "user": {
                "id": 1000000000,
                "is_bot": false,
                "first_name": "First Name",
                "username": "Username"
            }
        }
    ]
}

В первом случае getUser вернет null, во втором случае вы получите объект User.
(id, first_name и username являются лишь примером и не существуют на самом деле)

Можно ли в первом случае каким-либо другим способом получить информацию из @username?

Через telegram bot api - нельзя.
В telegram api есть функция getFullUser (https://core.telegram.org/method/users.getFullUser), возможно в поле id можно передать @username (или возможно я ошибаюсь и туда можно только user id)

Благодарю за ответ
